# Lodash - Group Children using N (repeated) keys for parent

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a select from database that basically joins a master entity and a child entity, like the example below (Cars vs Parts) as snippet

And I'd like to group by all the keys for the Car part, and have an array of the parts, but including all the keys for the car and the parts. For the groupBy examples I could find, generally it uses groupBy, but it only groups one key only. I was able to achieve using a lot of workarounds, but I'm sure it is manageable (and achieve more performance) to do the same using either es6 or lodash.

Could someone help me in this matter? I've tried multiple groupBy and reduce combinations, but was not able to chain those correctly.

```js
var data =     [{id: 'car1',
name: 'name for car 1',
description: 'description for car1',
partId: 'partId1',
partName: 'partName1'},
  
{id: 'car1',
name: 'name for car 1',
description: 'description for car1',
partId: 'partId2',
partName: 'partName2'},

{id: 'car2',
name: 'name for car 2',
description: 'description for car2',
partId: 'partId3',
partName: 'partName3'},

{id: 'car2',
name: 'name for car 2',
description: 'description for car2',
partId: 'partId4',
partName: 'partName4'}
];
   var dictionary = {};
 data.forEach(function(item, index, array)
  {
    var masterDocument = null;
    if (typeof dictionary[item.id] === 'undefined')
    {
      masterDocument = {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        description: item.description,
        parts: []
      };
      dictionary[item.id] = masterDocument;
    }
    else {
      var masterDocument = dictionary[item.id];
    }
    masterDocument.parts.push({
      partId: item.partId,
      partName: item.partName
    })
  })


  var asList = [];
  Object.keys(dictionary).forEach((item) => {
    asList.push(dictionary[item])
  });
  console.log(asList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here's the snippet with just the result I want to achieve.

```js
[
  {
    "id": "car1",
    "name": "name for car 1",
    "description": "description for car1",
    "parts": [
      {
        "partId": "partId1",
        "partName": "partName1"
      },
      {
        "partId": "partId2",
        "partName": "partName2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "car2",
    "name": "name for car 2",
    "description": "description for car2",
    "parts": [
      {
        "partId": "partId3",
        "partName": "partName3"
      },
      {
        "partId": "partId4",
        "partName": "partName4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the output that you want to achieve?

Comment: @dashmug sure, I've included it in the snipped, when you run it, you can see the json I want to achieve (but using my workarounds, and not es6/lodash). I'll update the question to include the desired json if that helps! tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should solve your problem using Lodash. Basically what you want to do is:

1. Group the cars by `id`
2. Once you have the cars grouped by their IDs, iterate over that top-level array with a map call, and grab the `id`, `name`, and `description` from the first entry (since you know these are all the same for all cars in this group). Save these for later for your return object
3. Then, while still in this top-level map iteration, also iterate over the individual cars in each carGrouping (a nested map) to get their `partId` and `partName`, and put those into a `parts` array
4. Finally, get all of your object attributes, put them all into a return object in your top-level map call, and return them all back
5. Don't forget to call `valueOf()` at the end of your chain to get the Lodash sequence to fire

```js
let data =  [{id: 'car1',
name: 'name for car 1',
description: 'description for car1',
partId: 'partId1',
partName: 'partName1'},

{id: 'car1',
name: 'name for car 1',
description: 'description for car1',
partId: 'partId2',
partName: 'partName2'},

{id: 'car2',
name: 'name for car 2',
description: 'description for car2',
partId: 'partId3',
partName: 'partName3'},

{id: 'car2',
name: 'name for car 2',
description: 'description for car2',
partId: 'partId4',
partName: 'partName4'}
];

const carsInfo = _(data)
    .groupBy('id')
    .map(carGrouping => {
      // all cars in this array have the same id, name, description, so just grab them from the first one
      const firstCarInGroup = _.first(carGrouping); 
      const id = firstCarInGroup.id;
      const name = firstCarInGroup.name;
      const description = firstCarInGroup.description;

      // do a nested map call to iterate over each car in the carGrouping, and grab their partId and partName, and return it in an object
      const parts = _.map(carGrouping, car => {
        return {
          partId: car.partId,
          partName: car.partName
        }
      });

      return {
        id,
        name,
        description,
        parts
      }
    })
    .valueOf();


    console.log(carsInfo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one uses no dependencies. Just plain ES6+.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'car1',
    name: 'name for car 1',
    description: 'description for car1',
    partId: 'partId1',
    partName: 'partName1'
  },
  {
    id: 'car1',
    name: 'name for car 1',
    description: 'description for car1',
    partId: 'partId2',
    partName: 'partName2'
  },
  {
    id: 'car2',
    name: 'name for car 2',
    description: 'description for car2',
    partId: 'partId3',
    partName: 'partName3'
  },
  {
    id: 'car2',
    name: 'name for car 2',
    description: 'description for car2',
    partId: 'partId4',
    partName: 'partName4'
  }
];

const nested = data.reduce((acc, part) => {
  let index = acc.findIndex(car => car.id === part.id)
  const { partId, partName, ...car } = part

  if (index === -1) {
    acc.push({
      ...car,
      parts: [],
    })

    index = acc.length - 1
  }

  acc[index].parts.push({
    partId,
    partName,
  })

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(nested, null, '  '));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it doesn't use lodash but it seems the simplest solution! Could you care to explain the "...car" syntax? tried looking for rest parameters, but couldn't understand as the car is not a parameter for the function reduce. Thanks!

Comment: `...car` is not a rest parameter. It's using [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).